# "t" statement in .bst file

Tags: bibtex

I changed the following function in a given `.bst` file

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { title "t" change.case$ }
  if$
}
```

to

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { title }
  if$
}
```

in order to avoid acronyms in my BibTex to become small case in the final `.pdf`. This seems to work (only keeping `title "t"` fails compiling).

I don't know how to program in the BibTeX language, but `change.case` is, I assume, a function call to change the string on top of the stack (`&`) to lower cases. Since I don't want to encounter possible strange side effects in the future, I am curious what the "t" part means?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function `change.case$` picks up the top two items in the stack and returns a string. With `title "t" change.case$` the two top items are the title and `"t"`.

The second argument to `change.case$` should be one of `"t"`, `"u"` or `"l"`; in the `"t"` case everything except the first letter is turned into lower case, with `"u"` everything is turned uppercase and with `"l"` everything is turned lowercase. But items at positive brace depth are kept untouched in any case.

With your change you're passing just `title` as the false branch for `if$`.

For more information, see Nicolas Markey's “Tame the BeaST”, available on [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/tamethebeast) (and in most TeX distributions as `texdoc tamethebeast`). The `change.case$` function is described on page 33.

Comment: Another great reference is BibTeXing by Oren Patashnik, dated Feb 8, 1988. (http://bibtexml.sourceforge.net/btxdoc.pdf)